# Creating a new bucket in Couchbase with Nodejs SDK

Tags: node.js, couchbase

From what I understand a `Bucket` in **Couchbase** is the same as a `Database` in **CouchDb** and a `node` is the same as a `document`. 
Are these deductions correct?

What then, is the code to create a `new Bucket` using the **NodeJs SDK**?
I cannot find the documentation for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that a `Bucket` in **Couchbase** is the same as a `Database` in **CouchDb** and other database systems. However a `Document` in **CouchDB** is the same as a `Document` in **Couchbase**. A **Couchbase** `Node` is a single server that is apart of the cluster.

The [Manual](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/#architecture-and-concepts) covers the high level concepts of couchbase in more details.

The current version ([1.2.4](http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-node-client-1.2.4/)) of the NodeJS SDK does not have the ability to create a `new bucket`. Couchbase does have [RESTful API](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-rest-api/#creating-and-editing-buckets) that allows the creation of buckets.

Couchbase are working on a new [2.0.0](http://blog.couchbase.com/nodejs-sdk-200-developer-preview) nodeJS that will support creating of buckets.